# Checking for all instances of a character in a string?

Tags: c++, visual-c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
#include "Header1.h"
using namespace std;
static const char * const wordDataBase[] = {"test","eee","office","minor","town","wrap","treatment","determined","blue","acrid","itchy","organic","impartial","frame","parallel","inconclusive","agreeable","stiff","obsequious","lonely","extra","large","crash","grease","tacky","bashful","cheap","island","outgoing","open","quick","general","big","related","rich","stain","cable","many","attract","star","governor","receive","four","best","tap","match","dapper","married","invent","coordinated","\0"};
string c;
//
char guess;
int wordPick;
bool crct = 0;
bool inct = 0;
int fails = 0;
//
int main() {
    cout << "Pick a number between 1 & 50: ";
    cin >> wordPick;
    string pickedWord = wordDataBase[wordPick - 1];
    int wordLength = pickedWord.length();
    char* pch;
    char str[] = " ";
        for (string::size_type l = 0; l < 6; ++l) {
            string::value_type c = pickedWord[l];
            cin >> guess;
            crct = 0;
            inct = 0;
            if (guess == c) {
                crct = 1;
            }
            else if (guess != c) {
                inct = 1;
                fails + 1;
            }
            if (crct == 1) {
                second();
                for (int guessLength = 0; guessLength < wordLength; guessLength++) {
                    cout << "_  ";
                } cout << endl;
                cout << endl << "You guessed a correct letter!" << endl << "Guess again! ";
                for (int i = 0; i < pickedWord.length(); ++i) {
                    str[i] = pickedWord[i];
                }
                pch = (char*)memchr(str, guess, strlen(str));
                if (pch != NULL)
                    printf("%d.\n", pch - str + 1);
                else
                    printf("guess not found.\n");
            }
            else if (inct == 1 && fails <= 6) {
                third();
                for (int guessLength = 0; guessLength < wordLength; guessLength++) {
                    cout << "_  ";
                } cout << endl;
                cout << endl << "You guessed an incorrect letter!" << endl << "Guess again! ";
            }
            else if (fails == 6) {
                third();
                for (int guessLength = 0; guessLength < wordLength; guessLength++) {
                    cout << "_  ";
                } cout << endl;
                cout << "Sadly, you've lost." << endl;
            }
        }
    return 0;
};
```

The code above is of a project I'm working on. In short, Hangman. Right now, it's working, sort of. But as of now, I can only guess if I guess the letters in the correct order. Any ideas on how I can fix this?

Also, any idea how I can check for all instances of a character in a string?

Comment: [`std::string::find`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find)?

Comment: Unrelated side note: `fails + 1;` will do nothing.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "check for all instances of a character"? Do you want to count all the instances? Find all of the indices?

Comment: Please check out this link: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. What have you tried to do to solve this, and what isn't working?

Comment: I've had a look at all your responses and fixed my code. Thank you all so much for your insight and constructive critique!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a possible solution. I used `std::string`s because they're just simpler. I hold the actual word, and the player's progress in two strings. It's simply a matter of going through the solution with the guess, character-by-character.

```cpp
  int process_guess(char guess) {
    int found = 0;
    guess = std::toupper(guess);

    if (!std::isalpha(guess)) {
      return found;
    }

    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < m_solution.length(); ++i) {
      if (m_solution[i] == guess) {
        m_attempt[i] = guess;
        ++found;
      }
    }

    if (!found) {
      --m_chances;
    }

    return found;
  }
```

This function also counts how many instances of the guess were found, it's not needed if you don't want that information.

Your variable names were not easy to read, making your code hard to read, so I spun my own little hangman. I'm including the class that enforces the rules to provide context for the function above:

```cpp
class Hangman {
 public:
  Hangman(std::string word)
      : m_solution(word), m_attempt(std::string(word.length(), '*')) {}

  std::string get_attempt() const { return m_attempt; }

  int get_chances_left() const { return m_chances; }

  int process_guess(char guess) {
    int found = 0;
    guess = std::toupper(guess);

    if (!std::isalpha(guess)) {
      return found;
    }

    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < m_solution.length(); ++i) {
      if (m_solution[i] == guess) {
        m_attempt[i] = guess;
        ++found;
      }
    }

    if (!found) {
      --m_chances;
    }

    return found;
  }

  bool game_over() const {
    for (auto c : m_attempt) {
      if (c == '*') {
        return !(m_chances > 0);
      }
    }

    return m_chances > 0;
  }

  void reset_game(std::string word) {
    m_solution = word;
    m_attempt = std::string(word.length(), '*');
    m_chances = 6;
  }

 private:
  std::string m_solution;
  std::string m_attempt;
  int m_chances = 6;
};
```

One thing it is currently not doing is recognizing if you guessed a letter already. I'll leave that to you whether it's a penalty or not.

Comment: Thank you so much for you help on my problem! I've taken in what you all have posted and come further with my project. May I ask how I can test your code (sweenish)?